# looking up a value in xml C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

given this xml (just a part..)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translations>
    <key name="BillOfMaterials">
    <translation culture="en-GB"><![CDATA[Bill of materials]]>
    </translation>
   <translation culture="da-DK"><![CDATA[Materiale liste]]>
    </translation>
    </key>
    <key name="TechnicalDetails">
    <translation culture="en-GB">
    <![CDATA[Technical details
    ]]>
    </translation>
    </key>
    ..
    ..
```

...i'm looking for the simplest solution to look up for instance:

so

```
string thisTranslation = GetTranslation("BillOfMaterials","en-GB"); //value gets to be "Bill of materials"
```

I have tried the linq way, but it gets rather messy with too many itherations... especially when a simple xpath is enough in xslt... But I can't seem to just do that

Thanks in advance

Edit:
- xml is physical file
- function may not find anything.....should then just return the original key name

```
 /translations/key[@name="BillOfMaterials"]/translation[@culture="en-GB"]
```

is the xpath that elsewhere is usable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still use LINQ to XML - there's absolutely no need for it to get messy:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
string key = "BillOfMaterials";
var element = doc.Root.Elements("key")
                      .Where(key => key.Attribute("name").Value == key)
                      .Elements("translation")
                      .Where(tr => tr.Attribute("culture").Value == "en-GB")
                      .FirstOrDefault();
string result = (string) element ?? key;
```

Personally I find that cleaner than using XPath (even though the XPath is undeniably shorter). It separates each section of the query more distinctly, and also if you need any namespace handling, that would be significantly simpler with LINQ to XML than messing around with namespace managers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`XPathSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelement%28v=vs.90%29) extension method set on XElement with your XPath selector:

Load your XML into an XDocument:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path\to\file");
```

and then search it with XPath:

```
var translation = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement(string.format("/translations/key[@name=\"{0}\"]/translation[@culture=\"{1}\"]", key, culture));
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(translation))
     translation = key;
return translation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get you Xml document in a `XmlDocument` type. You can do this like:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("<xml>"); // Can be a XML in a string, or filename, etc.
```

Then you can use `XPath` with the `SelectNodes()` and `SelectNode()` methods.

Like:

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/translations/key[@name=\"BillOfMaterials\"]/translation[@culture=\"en-GB\"]");
```